# C++ program running out of memory for large data

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I am trying to solve an issue in a C++ program I wrote. I am basically running out of memory. The program is a cache simulator. There is a file which has memory addresses collected beforehand, like this:

Thread    Address   Type    Size    Instruction Pointer
0   0x7fff60000000  1   8   0x7f058c482af3

There can be 100-500 billion such entries. First, I am trying to read all those entries and store it in a vector. Also while reading, I build up a set of these addresses (using map), and store the sequence numbers of a particular  address. Sequence number simply means the position of the address-entry in the file (one address can be seen multiple times). For large inputs the program fails while doing this, with a bad_alloc error at around the 30 millionth entry. I guess I am running out of memory. Please advise on how can I circumvent the problem. Is there an alternative way to handle this kind of large data. Thank you very much! Sorry for the long post. I wanted to give some context and the actual code which I am writing.

Below is the relevant code. The ParseTaceFile() reads each line and calls the 
StoreTokens(), which gets the address and size, and calls AddAddress() which actually stores the address in a vector and a map. The class declaration is also given below. The first try block in AddAddress() actually throws the bad_alloc exception.

```
void AddressList::ParseTraceFile(const char* filename) {
  std::ifstream in_file;
  std::cerr << "Reading Address Trace File..." << std::endl;
  in_file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
  char *contents = NULL;
  try {
    in_file.open(filename, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    in_file.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
    std::streampos length(in_file.tellg());
    if (length < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Can not read input file length" << std::endl;
      throw ExitException(1);
    }
    contents = (new char[length]);
    in_file.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);
    in_file.read(contents, length);
    in_file.close();
    uint64_t linecount = 0, i = 0, lastline = 0, startline = 0;
    while (i < static_cast<uint64_t>(length)) {
      if ((contents[i] == '\n') or (contents[i] == EOF)) {
        contents[i] = '\0';
        lastline = startline;
        startline = i + 1;
        ++linecount;
        if (linecount > 1) {
          StoreTokens((contents + lastline), &linecount);
        }
      }
      ++i;
    }
  } catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
    delete [] contents;
    std::cerr << "error allocating memory while parsing" << std::endl;
    throw;
  } catch (std::ifstream::failure &exc1) {
    if (!in_file.eof()) {
      delete[] contents;
      std::cerr << "error in reading address trace file" << exc1.what()
          << std::endl;
      throw ExitException(1);
    }
  }
  std::cerr << "Done" << std::endl;
}
//=========================================================    
void AddressList::StoreTokens(char* line, uint64_t * const linecount) {
  uint64_t address, size;
  char *token = strtok(line, " \t");
  uint8_t tokencount = 0;
  while (NULL != token) {
    ++tokencount;
    switch (tokencount) {
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      address = strtoul(token, NULL, 16);
      break;
    case 3:
      break;
    case 4:
      size = strtoul(token, NULL, 0);
      break;
    case 5:
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
  }
  AddAddress(address, size);
}
//================================================================
void AddressList::AddAddress(const uint64_t& byteaddr, const uint64_t& size) {

  //allocate memory for the address vector
  try {
    if ((sequence_no_ % kReserveCount) == 0) address_list_.reserve(kReserveCount);

  } catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
    std::cerr
        << "error allocating memory for address trace vector, address count"
        << sequence_no_ << std::endl;
    throw;
  }
  uint64_t offset = byteaddr & (CacheParam::Instance()->LineSize() - 1);
  //lineaddress = byteaddr >> CacheParam::Instance()->BitsForLine();
  // this try block is for allocating memory for the address set and the queue it holds
  try {
    // splitter
    uint64_t templinesize = 0;
    do {
      Address temp_addr(byteaddr + templinesize);
      address_list_.push_back(temp_addr);
      address_set_[temp_addr.LineAddress()].push(sequence_no_++);
      templinesize = templinesize + CacheParam::Instance()->LineSize();
    } while (size + offset > templinesize);
  } catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
    address_list_.pop_back();
    std::cerr
    << "error allocating memory for address trace set, address count"
    << sequence_no_ << std::endl;
    throw;
  }
 }

//======================================================
typedef std::queue<uint64_t> TimeStampQueue;
typedef std::map<uint64_t, TimeStampQueue> AddressSet;
class AddressList {
public:
  AddressList(const char* tracefilename);
  bool Simulate(uint64_t *hit_count, uint64_t* miss_count);
  ~AddressList();

private:
  void AddAddress(const uint64_t& byteaddr, const uint64_t& size);
  void ParseTraceFile(const char* filename);
  void StoreTokens(char* line, uint64_t * const linecount);

  std::vector<Address> address_list_;
  AddressSet address_set_;
  uint64_t sequence_no_;
  CacheMemory cache_;

  AddressList (const AddressList&);
  AddressList& operator=(const AddressList&);
};
```

The output is like this:

Reading Cache Configuration File...

Cache parameters read...

Reading Address Trace File...

error allocating memory for address trace set, address count 30000000

error allocating memory while parsing

Comment: Are you doing this on a 32 or 64 bit architecture?

Comment: @Abhi Estimate how much memory is required for storing that many records. Then figure out if a process can access that much memory on your particular machine/architecture.

Comment: @jdv 64 bit    @Vijay: The issue is I do not know the number of records. They are basically memory addresses accessed by a program. They will be large. depeneding on the program, 100 billion - 1 trillion or so.

Comment: 1 trillion pointers alone on a 64-bit system would require 8 TB of memory for storage. You may need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: Your platform probably simply doesn't allow that much memory to be allocated.  Try processing the file in chunks, if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems your datasets will be much larger then your memory you would have to write an on disk index. Probably easiest to import the whole thing into a database and let that build the indexes for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow this skipped my mind. SQLite solves this!

Answer (score 1):

A map sorts its input while it is being populated, to optimize lookup times and to provide a sorted output. It sounds like you aren't using the lookup feature, so the optimal strategy is to sort the list using another method. [Merge sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is fantastic for sorting collections that don't fit into memory. Even if you are doing lookups, a binary search into a sorted file will be faster than a naive approach as long as each record is a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for stating what may be obvious, but the need to store and query large amounts of data in an efficient manner is the exact reason databases were invented.  They have already solved all these issues in a better way than you or I could come up with in a reasonable amount of time.  No need to reinvent the wheel.